# MNIST AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, mnist

This is obviously working with the MNIST dataset. This code runs fine in Python v3.6.8 on my old computer but fails in v3.9.12. What is the answer to get this to work?

The error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 14>()
     10 examples = y.shape[0]
     11 #print(y.shape)
     12 #print(y)
---> 14 y = y.reshape(1, examples)
     15 Y_new = np.eye(digits)[y.astype('int32')]
     16 Y_new = Y_new.T.reshape(digits, examples)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

---

The code block:

```
# load MNIST dataset
X, y = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, return_X_y=True)
# prepare dataset
X = X / 255

digits = 10
examples = y.shape[0]
#print(y.shape)
#print(y)

y = y.reshape(1, examples)
Y_new = np.eye(digits)[y.astype('int32')]
Y_new = Y_new.T.reshape(digits, examples)

# set train test split
f = 60000
m_test = X.shape[0] - f

# split dataset into train and test
X_train, X_test = X[:f].T, X[f:].T
Y_train, Y_test = Y_new[:,:f], Y_new[:,f:]
np.random.seed(1)
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(f)
X_train, Y_train = X_train[:, shuffle_index], Y_train[:, shuffle_index]
print(X_train.shape[0])
print(X_train.shape[1])
```

Was preparing the MNIST dataset for training with a neural network.  I was expecting it to shape the data as it had in a previous version of Python.

Comment: `y = y.reshape(1, examples)` should instead be `y = np.reshape(1, examples)` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: This is [`sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml.html)? If so, target return can be _target: np.array, pandas Series or DataFrame_. So, the question would be why you get a different target on different machines. Right after `fetch_openml`, you could `assert isinstance(y, np.ndarray)` and get rid of the rest of the script as not relevant.

Comment: Making progress!  Thank you!!  That change got me past the initial issue but, alas, another cropped up.  .---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

---> 27 X_train, Y_train = X_train[:, shuffle_index], Y_train[:, shuffle_index]

InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), array([15281, 21435, 44536, ...,  5192, 12172, 33003]))